# PowerShell: select lines from object collection where property -lt X

Tags: powershell

so I have this table in variable $res

hostname     OSshort     freeGBonC

---

server1    w2k12       29,23
server2    w2k12       32,10
server3    w2k12       19,26

I can't seem to understand how to select lines with freeGBonC lower then some value. If I try

```
$res|where {$_.freeGBonC -lt 6}
```

it shows all lines! If I do -gt 6 it shows nothing! What kind of logic is this?

Comment: What does `$res[0].freeGBonC.GetType()` return?

Comment: I think you are trying to compare an array to an integer, causing unexpected results.

Comment: Jeez so it turns out somehow it was a string although looking like a number! I have fixed it, however I am confused about the -lt -gt behavior with string and number 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the values on the property `freeGBonC` are of the type `string` hence why the comparison is showing unexpected results.

Try using this, I think it should work:

```sh
$csv = @'
"hostname","OSshort","freeGBonC"
"server1","w2k12","29,23"
"server2","w2k12","32,10"
"server3","w2k12","19,26"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv | Where-Object {[double]$_.freeGBonC.Replace(',','.') -lt 29}
```

Results:

```
hostname OSshort freeGBonC
-------- ------- ---------
server3  w2k12   19,26
```

---

<strike>I guess PowerShell is smart enough to compare the `string` with a `double` as long as the `double` has the correct sign (`.`) so casting `[double]` or `[decimal]` is not even needed</strike>. Note that, `,` is for `arrays`.

```
PS \> $csv.freeGBonC.ForEach({$_.Replace(',','.') -lt 29})
False
False
True
```

Thanks [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69756226/powershell-select-lines-from-object-collection-where-property-lt-x/69756400?noredirect=1#comment123303264_69756400) for pointing this out, it is in fact needed to cast `[double]` if the `string` is on the left hand side of the operator else we will get unwanted results:

```
'10.0' -lt 2 # => True
2 -gt '10.0' # => False
[double]'10.0' -lt 2 # => False
```